# How to Scroll a Panel through code?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have a Panel that I wish to scroll horizontally through code,
the problem is that it only seems to scroll every second time the line of code is executed.
This is what Im using

```
 private void MyScrollButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    MainPanel.HorizontalScroll.Value += 64;
 }
```

This is what happens every time,

```
1st Click: Panel Scrolls and ScrollBar Remains Still
2nd Click: Panel remains still and ScrollBar scrolls
3rd Click: Same as 1st
4th Click: Same as 2nd
```

....
...
Repeat

Comment: Try changing it to `+= 32` and see if it only scrolls every forth time. This will teach us that the scrolling is actually done on a certain minimal difference, maybe around the `delta = 100`.

Comment: I tried `+=32`, and `+=16`.
It still scrolls every 2nd time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `AutoScrollPosition` instead (and you need to inverse the value):

```
private void MyScrollButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MainPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(-MainPanel.AutoScrollPosition.X + 64,
                                           -MainPanel.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
}
```